# updating a specific table after changes in the view values

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers

I have searched a lot and even wrote a post here which was closed. So I try to rephrase my question and simplify it.

I have a table created out of a view. There is a case that the values of the select statement that ruled the view can be changed. Now my question is: Is there a way that I can compare my view values with the table and whenever a change happens, the changes will be updated in my table?
One important point is that in my table I also have the uid column which is generated using function uuid_generate_v4() and this column is referenced in 3 more other tables using FK. So using materialized view seems problematic.

Comment: This sounds like you want a [MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

Comment: @clamp: I understand that Materialized View is storing physically the data like a table. If so: the problem is that I am not allowed to save the data of view on my side. And the table I create is an aggregation of some of the values provided in the view. (the view contains individual-based values and is queried from tables provided through a Foreign data wrapper connection)

Comment: I don't see why you can not create a materialized view using the statement that you used to populate the table...

Comment: @clamp: Doesn't a materialized view store the data physically like a table?

Comment: Yes it does - and so does your table...

Comment: With the materialized view you can [refresh](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). But- perhaps I don't get your question.

Comment: oh... Ok I got your point. I thought you meant instead of view, I may need to use Materialized View.